# How to store data in Vercel as a JSON object and consume it in react app as an API like we do for the case of Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, vercel

I have a requirement where I need to send GET and POST requests to Vercel to store and retrieve the data like we do in case of Firebase in the form of JSON object. Can this be done with Vercel?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for hosting the backend API. [Cyclic](https://www.cyclic.sh/) is a platform that can be used to host backend APIs, especially those built with Node.js and Express.js.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel is a platform for frontend hosting, not for full stack web applications. If you want to deploy a full stack application using Vercel you could use Vercel for your front-end and use some kind of cloud service to persist and fetch your data like MongoDB Atlas.

To access the cloud service where you are storing your data you could use [serverless functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions) that are provided by Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another that allows put and delete in json file: [Render](https://render.com/)